# Leaflet GEOpoly with Links

Tags: leaflet, geo

My site uses Leaflet to build a map with [multiple county outlines](https://www.msholmes.org/neighbors). Embedded within each GEOPoly file is a feature to indicate the website for the county. This all works great. BUT, what I would like to do is have the link include a target"_blank". How can this be done?

TIA for any assistance
jdadwilson

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: This is the code for one area...```var geoJsonLayer_attala = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(window.SERVER_PATH + "files_geojson/geopoly_attala.json",
  {style: {color: "DarkGray", weight: 2, fillColor: "Green"},
   onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { layer.bindTooltip('Attala', {permanent: true, offset: [30,0], className: 'marker_tooltip'}),
             layer.on('click', function () { window.location = CO_URL_LINK['Attala']}) } }).addTo(map);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your click function:

```
layer.on('click', function () { 
    window.open(CO_URL_LINK['Attala'], '_blank');
})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158856/8283938

Comment: Almost worked... needed target="_blank" to work! Thanks!!